# Is there a way of "echoing" to stdout what is being redirected as stdin to a program (Unix)?

Tags: linux, unix, redirect, echo, show

Say I have a program that that grabs information about a user from console.

```
$ ./program
Enter your name : Foo
Enter your phone number : Bar
Your name is Foo and phone number Bar.
```

Now if I don't want to manually enter "Foo" and "Bar", but instead want to redirect the input from a file...

**inputfile.txt**

```
Foo  
Bar
```

This is what happens with the output...

```
$ ./program < inputfile.txt
Enter your name : 
Enter your phone number : 
Your name is Foo and phone number Bar.
```

With the redirection, you can't see what was entered after the colon. Is there a way to make the input visible on console (like the first example)?

Edit : This is basically the same question that this thread asks:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228954/c-how-to-redirect-from-a-file-to-cin-and-display-as-if-user-typed-the-input

But I only found suggestions about changing the program and adding the function `isatty` , but is there a way without changing the existing program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wil depend on your program. I found a trick for the program

```
printf "%s : " "Enter your name"
read  name
printf "%s : " "Enter your phone number"
read  phone
echo "Your name is ${name} and phone number ${phone}"
```

Here you can use

```
while read -r line; do
   sleep 1
   echo "${line}"
done < inputfile.txt | tee >(./program)
```

This will fail when the program is changed into

```
read -p "Enter your name : " name
read -p "Enter your phone number : " phone
echo "Your name is ${name} and phone number ${phone}"
```

So you can test this solution and hope for the best.

Answer (score 0):

`tee /dev/tty < inputfile.txt | program` will echo the contents of the file, but it won't match up with your prompts. It'd look something like

```
$ tee /dev/tty < inputfile.txt | ./program
Foo
Bar
Enter your name : 
Enter your phone number : 
Your name is Foo and phone number Bar.
```

I don't think there is a way to get everything aligned like you want.